# Determine parentFrameId via chrome.scripting.executeScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

If I have a page with iFrames, a call to `chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames` returns an object that includes the parentFrameId and frameId properties for those iFrame and I can determine the hierarchy of those frames.

A call to `chrome.scripting.executeScript` injects a script into all frames and returns an "injectionResults" object that has the frameId but not the parentFrameId. The injection results can include results from the injected script.

Is there a way in JavaScript or the chrome methods, for the injected script to determine the parentFrameId for the current frame? This is hard to Google because all the results show how to get the html id of the parent iframe, not the parentFrameId.

This would save me calling getAllFrames to build the relationships of the frames.

Comment: getAllFrames is the only method, but you can also build the hierarchy by observing and accumulating webNavigation.onCommitted.

Comment: OK, thanks. At least I know the work is not in vain. Did you want to make this an answer?